# Предварительно объявление структуры

Tags: c++, структуры, объявление

Есть две структуры, реализующие геометрические понятия точки и вектора. Для инициализации вектора требуется две точки. Аналогично присутствует операция сложения точки и вектора через перегрузку оператора +. Компилятор ругается на отсутствие структуры Vector в перегрузке, что понятно, т.к. она реализована после. Каким образом предварительно объявить структуру Vector. (struct Vector;) не работает. Или тут ошибка самой логики объявления.

```
struct Vector;

struct Point
{

    int X;
    int Y;

    [***] 

    Point operator + (const Vector& ab)
    {
        this->X += ab.X;
        this->Y += ab.Y;
        return *this;
    }
};


struct Vector
{
    int X;
    int Y;

    [***]

    Vector(Point& a, Point& b)
    {
        X = b.X - a.X;
        Y = b.Y - a.Y;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С логикой предварительного объявления все в порядке. Просто определение вашего оператора надо делать там, где определения обоих классов уже *полностью известны*. Т.е. не внутри первого класса, а снаружи - после обоих определений классов, как `inline`

```
inline Point Point::operator + (const Vector& ab)
{
    this->X += ab.X;
    this->Y += ab.Y;
    return *this;
}
```

Внутри первого класса должно остаться только объявление оператора.

Однако реализовано у вас тут нечто странное. Бинарный оператор `+`, который вдруг ни с того ни с сего портит (модифицирует) свой первый операнд - это ужасно. Зачем вам понадобился такой странный оператор?

Comment: Действительно это ужасно, ошибка реализации, уже исправил на возврат нового объекта, спасибо. В процессе изучения перегрузки операторов C++.

Answer (score 2):

Вынесите определение оператора вне класса, после объявлений обоих классов. В классе оставьте только объявление оператора, без тела. Примерно так:

```
struct Vector;

struct Point
{

    int X;
    int Y;

    [***] 

    Point operator + (const Vector& ab);
};


struct Vector
{
    int X;
    int Y;

    [***]

    Vector(Point& a, Point& b)
    {
        X = b.X - a.X;
        Y = b.Y - a.Y;
    }
};

Point Point::operator + (const Vector& ab);
{
    X += ab.X;
    Y += ab.Y;
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что для того, чтобы разместить какой-то объект в классе, компилятор должен знать его размер. Поэтому вы не можете запихнуть еще не описанный объект в ваш класс - никак... кроме указателя или ссылки. Дело в том, что их размеры всегда одинаковы, независимо от объектов, на какие они указывают. Что же касается указания имени класса, для объявления указателя (или ссылки) на него, то просто пишите

```
class my_class;
```

перед классом, в котором будете размещать указатель на `my_class`.

UPD говоря класс - я имел ввиду понятие в общем, а не конкретно `class`